# How to srtip all html from page layout in Magento2

Tags: magento2, pdf

I am creating a module to generate dynamic product PDFs with  [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) My problem is I cant get the pdf to render / download as there is already html on the page.

I have created a layout template at Me/MyMod/view/frontent/layout/productpdf_index.xml

```
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Modzinc\Productpdf\Block\Product\View\Link"
               name="modzinc.dynamicpdf.linddsk"
               template="Modzinc_Productpdf::product/view/thepdf.phtml"
                after="-">
        </block>
     </referenceContainer>
 </body>
```

And I have a template file thepdf.phtml

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='example2.pdf'");
$pdf->Output('example2.pdf', 'I');
```

Now the pdf libary works but I am getting a page rendered as so

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�r 
Q�w3T04�30PISp  �Z*�[����(hx����+���(j*�d��7W 
endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> stream 
x�]R�n�0��>��L�%�DI�8���~�%E*r�ﻻvҪHX�gvVk? /
���Ῑ��`]�[�x5 �3\z��P�}
����PO���j�Jݍ^���x6/f�����������|���4}�z�����}
���@�,ۖ-��˺E�u�^�,���<� �Z_�K� IQ����Yd����C�K�_�%q�8>�!J"V!2&bGģ%r"H��D��\}2EL1n��h�j���e��"a*H����:��d��9c���[�X1~��"�3�g��Ñ�;O��> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 6 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.81) /CreationDate (D:20170512141922) >> endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R >> endobj xref 0 9 0000000000 65535 f 0000000228 00000 n 0000000867 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000315 00000 n 0000000749 00000 n 0000000971 00000 n 0000001047 00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 8 0 R /Info 7 0 R >> startxref 1096 %%EOF
```

Now I know why this is its because my page mysiet.com/productpdf is rendering all the usual magento head html and body class stuff so the pdf wont work as the header has already been declared.

I need to know how what I need to put in my page layout file ( productpdf_index_index.xml ) To tell magento just load the thepdf.phtml template file with NO ! other markup, like a completely blank page.

Can anyone help me I suppose I just need a new Blank page layout but I cant figure out how to do it

thanks in advcance